# Openlayers 2.11 and Jquery Mobile 1.0.1 are not working together

Tags: jquery-mobile, openlayers

I have been working on a project with OpenLayers and jquery Mobile. Whenever I write the code to run without Jquery Mobile, OpenLayers works perfectly. The problem comes when I put them together. The map never loads. What am I doing wrong? Is there something I have to take into account that I am missing?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>ISEC App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />


    <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min"></script>

    <!--  If I comment this line, everything works fine -->
    <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js">      </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/mapa.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>


  <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="mapas"></div>


  <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">    


    var mapa = new OpenLayers.Map('mapas');
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
        "Isec", "http://www.isec.com.co/osm/tiles/z${z}/ln${x}/lt${y}.png",
        {numZoomLevels: 18}
    );
    mapa.addLayer(wms);

    mapa.setCenter(lonLatT(-74.1185,4.6867), 14);

    alert("*/*/*");



    function lonLatT(lon, lat){
    return new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
    }
  </script>

</body>

<html>
```

If I remove the reference to the jquery.mobile javascript file, it works. I don't understand why it is working that way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1)Your not formatting your page like a jquery mobile page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="mapPage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Map</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="mapa"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2) Call your map from inside pageinit. I would recommend moving all you javascript into the head of your document or better yet make an external js file.

```
$(document).delegate('#mapPage','pageinit',function(){
    mapa.addLayer(wms);

    mapa.setCenter(lonLatT(-74.1185,4.6867), 14);

    alert("*/*/*");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Codaniel. I rewrote and reorganized the code as you suggested, but I still don't see the map. I can see the alert function's message but no map. If don't include the jquery-mobile library the map loads but I don't get the nice look and feel. Is there any compatibility issue with jquery-mobile and OpenLayers I am not aware of? What else could I do?

Comment: Hmm maybe it is a conflict. I'm not real sure. I don't have much experience with open layers.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue as well. The problem is jQuery Mobile's page layout interferes with the size calculations of the OpenLayers.Map object. What you have is a viewer that is full width, but zero height.

Here's what we did (most of this code was adapted from the [JQuery Mobile example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-jq.html))

Firstly, override the OpenLayers.Map.getCurrentSize() function:

```
OpenLayers.Map.prototype.getCurrentSize = function() {
    var mapDiv = $(this.div);
    return new OpenLayers.Size(mapDiv.width(), mapDiv.height());
};
```

Secondly, we structured the JQM page like so:

```
<div data-role="page">
     <div data-role="header">
         <h3>Map Viewer</h3>
     </div>
     <div data-role="content" id="viewerContainer">
         <div id="viewer">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div data-role="footer">
         <h3>My footer</h3>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then we put in a functions to prep the correct container height for the OpenLayers map and to ensure the correct height afterwards

```
function fixContentHeight(olMap) {
    var footer = $("div[data-role='footer']:visible"),
        content = $("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible"),
        viewHeight = $(window).height(),
        contentHeight = viewHeight - footer.outerHeight();

    if ((content.outerHeight() + footer.outerHeight()) !== viewHeight) {
        contentHeight -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height() + 1);
        content.height(contentHeight);
    }
    content.width($(window).width());
    olMap.updateSize();
}

function ensureNonZeroHeight(containerid) {
    var footer = $("div[id='" + containerid + "'] > div[data-role='footer']"),
        header = $("div[id='" + containerid + "'] > div[data-role='header']"),
        content = $("div[id='" + containerid + "'] > div[data-role='content']"),
        viewHeight = $(window).height(),
        contentHeight = viewHeight - footer.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight();

    if ((content.outerHeight() + footer.outerHeight() + header.outerHeight()) !== viewHeight) {
        contentHeight -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height() + 1);
        content.height(contentHeight);
        content.width($(window).width());
    }
 }
```

Then finally, the OpenLayers.Map is set up like so:

```
ensureNonZeroHeight("viewerContainer");
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("viewer", { /* other options */ });
/* Other map initialization code */
fixContentHeight(map);
```

And ensure that fixContentHeight() is called whenever this page is presented.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I tried what you wrote, but I am afraid it is still not working. Check this page: http://www.isec.com.co/movilidad/jquery/index.html